# Check is member in struct with C

Tags: c, struct

I want to access to member in struct but check if this member exist

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct MyStruct { int a;};
    struct MyStruct temp ;
    temp.a=3;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to check if member `a` is in struct m and if not access to b with `#ifdef` ?
something like `#ifdef MyStruct.a temp.a=3; #else temp.b=3; #endif`

Comment: The compiler will reject your code if the member doesn't exist.  No, there isn't an automatic way to detect whether a member exists in a structure for use with conditional compilation.  You could manually sett up code such as `#define MEMBER_A_EXISTS 1` or `#define MEMBER_A_EXISTS 0` depending on whether member `a` exists, and then testing that macro.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — what's your real problem?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, so I want to check it before compilation

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: If `a` doesn't exist, will `b` be the first member of the `struct MyStruct`? in this case there is a solution: `*(int *)&temp = 3;` (the first member of a `struct` and the `struct` itself are interchangeable through a cast)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler or _is_ there? https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25178503

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou nops, `offsetof`, `sizeof` and minions can not be used inside an `#if` directive, furthermore in `offsetof(struct MyStruct, a)` , `a` is evaluated at compile time giving a compilation error (in the case of `a` not being defined).

Comment: @DavidRanieri you're right, my bad. I glanced at the question and thought it was asking something else (i.e. can you check if a pointer is a member of a particular struct)

Comment: Before you use _any_ variable in C, you (the programmer) need to look at the declaration of that variable. Every time, every case, no exceptions. Code completion IDEs might be helpful when dealing with large and complex structs, if you can't figure out how to use "go to declaration" in your IDE.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do in C.

The usual way if you *really* want to detect a member of a struct, is to first compile a sample program that uses the struct, see if the compilation succeeds and depending on the result define or not a preprocessor macro to the compiler used to compile the rest of the project. Various [build systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) were created to ease up such tasks. A short example with `cmake` may look like the following:

```
cat >mystruct.h <<EOF
struct MyStruct { 
    int a; // a? maybe not? no one knows.
};
EOF
```

```
cat >CMakeLists.txt <<EOF
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test_include C)
# will try to compile a testing file
try_compile(mystruct_has_a "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_mystruct_has_a.c)
add_executable(main main.c)
if(mystruct_has_a)
    target_compile_definitions(main PUBLIC MYSTRUCT_HAS_A)
endif()
EOF
```

```
cat >test_mystruct_has_a.c <<EOF
#include "mystruct.h"
int main() {
    struct MyStruct temp;
    temp.a = 3; // test - can we compile this?
}
EOF
```

```
cat >main.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mystruct.h"
int main() {
    struct MyStruct temp ;
#if MYSTRUCT_HAS_A
    // it's ok to use `temp.a` here.
    temp.a = 3;
    printf("%d\n", temp.a);
#endif
}
EOF
```

Which can be compiled with from the command line:

```
cmake -S. -B_build && cmake --build _build --verbose
```

`cmake` will try to compile file `test_mystruct_has_a.c`. If the compilation is successful, then the macro `MYSTRUCT_HAS_A` will be added as a macro to compiler arguments. If not, the macro will not be added. Then `main.c` will compile with that macro or without depending on the previous result. Such a way is typically used in many, many various projects mostly to provide portability by detecting operating system specific stuff, from top of my head for example members of `sigaction`, `siginfo_t` or `sched_param`.